# Covariance with undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, undefined, typechecking

The following code is clearly incorrectly typed, yet I cannot make TypeScript error on it.  I turned on `strict`, as well as `strictNullChecks` and `strictFunctionTypes` for good measure, but TS remains unwavering in its conviction that this code is fine and dandy.

```
abstract class A {
    // You can pass an undefined to any A
    public abstract foo(_x: number | undefined);
}

class B extends A {
    // B is an A, but it prohibits passing in an undefined.
    // Note that if we did `x: string`, TS would flag it as
    // an error.
    public foo(x: number) {
        if (x === undefined) {
            throw new Error("Type error!");
        }
    }
}

function makeAnA(): A {
    // This typechecks correct, so B is clearly an A, in
    // TS's opinion.
    return new B();
}

function test() {
    const b = makeAnA();
    // b is a B, so this should not be possible
    b.foo(undefined);
}
```

Is this expected behavior?  Is there some option I can turn on that will flag this as an error?  I've had this bite me more than once.

Comment: Well. I'm reading this: b is a B, but it is disguised as an A. Your disguise is working properly.

Comment: Yep - your `b` is improperly typed as an A. Use `const b = new B();` and the error comes up as expected. Declaring the type of a variable with `:` when declaring it is rarely useful, in my experience, TS can almost always automatically detect its type sufficiently

Comment: While the type checker does not complain, your definition of `B` violates basic subtyping assumptions and should be revised. Given `function useA(a: A) { a.foo(undefined); }`, that `useA(new B)` throws is definitely a bad thing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, `B` violates basic subtyping rules, which is why TS should complain - it's a type error. Note that if, for example, I type `B.foo` as `foo(x: string)`, TS does error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design decision. All method parameters behave bivariantly. This means that as far as ts is concerned, for methods `(_x: number) => void` is a subtype of to `(_x: number | number) => void` (and vice-versa). This is obviously unsound.

Initially not only method parameters behaved bivariantly but all function signature parameters. To fix this, the `strictFuctionTypes` flag was added in typescript 2.6. From the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654):

> With this PR we introduce a --strictFunctionTypes mode in which function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly instead of bivariantly. The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in method or constructor declarations. **Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode).**
>
> (highlight added)

So here we get a glimpse into the decision to have methods parameters continue to relate bivariantly. It's for convenience. Without this unsoundness, most classes would be invariant. For example if `Array` were invariant, `Array<Dog>` would not be a subtype of `Array<Animal>`, creating all sort of pain points in pretty basic code.

While definitely not equivalent, if we use a function field instead of a method (with `strictFunctionTypes` turned on), we do get an error that `Type '(x: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(_x: number | undefined) => void'`

```
abstract class A {
    // You can pass an undefined to any A
    public foo!: (_x: number | undefined) => void;
}

class B extends A {
    // Error here
    public foo: (x: number) => void = x => {
        if (x === undefined) {
            throw new Error("Type error!");
        }
    }
}

function makeAnA(): A {
    //And here 
    return new B();
}

function test() {
    const b = makeAnA();
    // b is a B, so this should not be possible
    b.foo(undefined);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIQHpiEBNAewFclgA7BABzQwYWvoBMBTAMwCW9HlwQRKCBgE8sBIk2ohkA2Aj6VKAQgBcCABQB9AB6761ALYgeUBAB8O3fkJEBKBAF4AfAgBulAVwA3HgAvnh4KKwIAEIIPEYQPNwY2PhEJGQAolBQlDYAFtY8coQKSipqGrp6JghmltZuXr7+ou4IRh7eaelEAnz6ne7DDryCwlxuPb29EPm5AO51PEvZuVB6AEQAKlJMPHE5eZqbLsEzhGHpYWF4fJzwApSM5sAA1jyY9Jh6LrqpJQymC4jEKUAOgPBEGoUEYwiW0V+wVu93oj2eYh4kF+uEBsGekAQIA8CFeHy+PzOgNIRIQAjYMQANAgwBI5vSWfkaMhRPRKIgrMxKOgBEpiukQAA6dSUPScMbOSbIvBAA)

**Note**: The code above gives an error only with `strictFunctionTypes` as without it all function parameter continue to behave bivariantly.

Comment: Just to avoid any irrelevant distractions, could you consider using `public foo(x: number): void {` in your example instead? It just seems like unnecessary noise in your otherwise perfect answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not sure where you mean? In the beginning ? Or in the sample code  at the end (there the noise is required, `foo` must be a field not a method to get the error, that is part of the point I am making )

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but when I change it to what I suggested in your playground link, I still get the same error. In fact, with the field syntax, I _don't_ get the error when I uncheck `strictFunctionTypes` in the flags (while the error persists with the class method syntax).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Without `strictFunctionTypes` all function parameters continue to behave bivariantly, so you would not get an error (i'll highlight that in the answer). With method syntax you won't get an error, that is the motivation of the question (maybe some gost  errors were left over) : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIQAcBXEZAS1gQDMB7egCgH0APALgQDtSBbEAFMoCAD4JS3ACaDalboKkBKBBwBu9SlNwBfPHrwo0GAEIJBbCIOkZs+IggD0jgGLzBCAkTIVqdRkycPPxCUErqmtr2RHoGtJLwlPTcCHzAANaCmNyYTOFYuF6EzghuCkUIUIIQpFApCgDuCCZ5ANz6eEA

Comment: This is what I was suggesting: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIQHpiEBNAewFclgA7BABzQwYWvoBMBTAMwCW9HlwQRKCBgE8sBIk2ohkA2JPDQ4iPpUoAuBAAoA+gA999agFsQPKAgA+HbvyEiAlAgC8APgQA3SgEuAG48AF88PBRWBAAhBB4TCB5uDGx8IhIyAFEoKEo7AAtbHjlCBSUVBG1KAzMEC2tbN30AoNwyzIQBPkMTL09PJ15BYS4PDK6piEL8gHcGngXc-KgDACIAFSkmHgS8goBCdbdQqcIIzIiIvD5OeAFKRktgAGseTHpMAxasDszSJguIxilA9p0wRBqFBGMIFrEfqEbnd6A8nmIeJAfv8iLAnpAECAvAgXu9Pt9Tp1SITumw4gAaBBgCQzAQYMCFGjIUT0SiIGzMSjoARKUqZEAAOhqBk4I1c4yReCAA

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ah, overriding a field with a method. Yeah, that could work. I am a bit weary of mixing the two .. Although I'll admit I have no good reason for it

Comment: I understand that semantically, the base class is referring to an _own_ property rather than a prototype property, and that maybe in a future version of TypeScript (with an additional flag) it would break. I can understand your weariness